# C++ List equivalent with C# List

Tags: c#, c++, list, arraylist

I have some simple question. I am trying to create a List in C++ that equivalent with C# List. My purpose is to creating a List that can contain some offset that I have create. So at finally my `COffset` will contain with 200 list of my offset like this

```
1.{ 0xAC, 0x10, 0x8, 0x4 }

2.{ 0xAC, 0x10, 0x8, 0x8, 0x4 }

3.{ 0xAC, 0x10, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x4 }
.
.
.
200.{ 0xAC, 0x10, 0x8, ........., 0x8, 0x4}
```

My C# Code:

```
 private int[] CRead;
 private int[] CCheck = { 0xAC, 0x10, 0x8, 0x4 };
 List<int[]> COffset = new List<int[]>();
 private int NumPointer = 204;
 private void CalculateOffset()
    {
        for (int i = 4; i < NumPointer ; i++)
        {
            CRead = (int[])ResizeArray(CCheck, i);
            CRead[i - 1] = 0x4;
            CRead[i - 2] = 0x8;
            CCheck = CRead;

            COffset.Add(CRead);
        }
    }
 private static System.Array ResizeArray(System.Array oldArray, int newSize)
    {
        int oldSize = oldArray.Length;
        System.Type elementType = oldArray.GetType().GetElementType();
        System.Array newArray = System.Array.CreateInstance(elementType, newSize);

        int preserveLength = System.Math.Min(oldSize, newSize);

        if (preserveLength > 0)
            System.Array.Copy(oldArray, newArray, preserveLength);

        return newArray;
    }
```

**This works very well in C# with no error.** But now I am trying to make it work with C++.First I need to tell that I am just beginning learning C++.

> **My question is does it have any equivalent code to this C# code?**

My C++ progress code:

```
static int CRead[]; //*Can't create this because it have to tell the size.
static int CCheck[] = { 0xAC, 0x10, 0x8, 0x4 };
list<int[]> COffset; //*don't know that it is correct or not. I don't know how to test it without fully done.
                     //#include <list> for using list
static int NumPointer = 204;
static void CalculateOffset(){
   for(int i =4 ; i<NumPointer ; i++){
      //This steps I have no idea at all because its need ResizeArray in C#.
   }
}
```

All the comment that I indicate is the part that I don't have any idea how to make it work. For example in `CRead` I can't assign the size of it because it is not a constant as you can see in C# code.

Comment: There is `vector`. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/

Comment: As a note: there is already a C# Array.Resize method. There is no need need to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to set last element as `0x8` and then append `0x4`, there's not need to do so much explicit resizing by yourself, that'd be taken care of by - `std::vector`. I am keeping `CCheck` for this. It will have it's last element updated to `0x8` and then we'll will append `0x4` to it, making it the vector you'd want at iteration `i`:

```
vector<int> CCheck;
CCheck.push_back(0xAC);
CCheck.push_back(0x10);
CCheck.push_back(0x8 );
// Notice i am keeping only 3 members in CCCheck.
vector< vector< int > >  COffset;

for (int i = 4; i < NumPointer ; i++)
    {
        //Set last element as 0x08.
        CCheck[ i - 2] = 0x8; // Why i - 2 ; You want to set second last element to 0x8 which can be computed via "i - 2" or  "CCheck.size() - 1".
        //Now Insert last 0x4 and put it into COffset.
        CCheck.push_back(0x4);
        COffset.push_back(CCheck);
    }
```

Moreover, if your compiler supports C++11, you can do this - instead of pushing elements one by one:

```
  vector<int> CCheck = {0xAC, 0x10, 0x8}; // Again, only three elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

For all the problem you listed the `std::vector` is the solution. Try it or other standard container ( maybe `std::list` could be fine ) to solve this problem.

I leave you 2 useful link to these construct:

[vector](https://it.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

[list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/)

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with C#, but [it seems that `List` would be an `std::vector`](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/articles/cplus_equivalent_to_csharp_list.html).

What I do know is stuff like `int[]` is also an [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Generally, anytime you don't know the size in C++, use an `std::vector`.

Note that `std::vector` has a [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) function already, so you won't have to make one yourself. You can also [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) an element when you need one, and the vector handles it for you. No need to worry about size.